# issues with GNU tail -f and combination of commands

Tags: shell, scripting, quoting, ksh

```
$ tail -f /logs/filename.log | awk '!(/list)'
```

I am able to run this command in GNU Linux flavour

But when I written in a script it is not working.

test.ksh:

```
variable="/logs/filename.log | awk '!(/list)'" 
tail -f $var
```

Getting the error as

```
tail: cannot open `|' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open `grep' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open `list' for reading: No such file or directory
```

How is need to work on this? Can anyone guide on this?

Comment: For first, I see no way the original one could work as the `awk` code has syntax error.

Comment: What the others are saying is that you can't put a pipe or other shell special characters into a string and then hope the shell can read your mind. You can however use `eval`, but that's generally not advised.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is broken in a couple of ways...

- You define a variable with the name `variable`, then call it with the name `var`. That won't work.
- I can't make out what you were trying to accomplish with the variable in the first place because the quoting is so screwy. The interpreter will have the more problems than I did ;-) In effect, you are sending a string that looks like a set of commands including a pipeline -- but since they are inside of a quoted string as an argument to another command, they will just come across as so many characters in a text blob as an argument. Not something the interpreter will touch.

Perhaps you want something like this in your `test.ksh` file:

```
#!/bin/ksh
log_file="/logs/filename.long"
tail -f $log_file | awk '!(/list)'
```

Or even this which you would run with a command like `./test.ksh /logs/filename.log`:

```
#!/bin/ksh
tail -f $1 | awk '!(/list)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote 2 different things.

In the shell, you stated that the output of tail -f is redirected to awk

In your script, you stated that tail -f should read data from the files named "/logs/filename.log", "|", "awk" and "!(/list)"

You want to write this in your script file:

```
#!/bin/ksh
variable="/logs/filename.log"
tail -f $variable | awk '!(/list)'
```